# Would Elasticsearch work better with a document database like MongoDB or a relational database like MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, elasticsearch, nosql

I am trying to decide which database to build my site on, it will have a similar structure to sites like [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com). I have decided I would like to use Elaticsearch (for searches) in combination with another database (as a primary datastore). What type of database would work better with Elasticsearch, a NoSQL (probably document database) like MongoDB or an SQL relational database like MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on your use-cases primary datastore, if you want to have a

1. Key-based lookup (mentioning on key-value, document-based NoSQL)
2. Simple queries on a few columns
3. Ok to not have ACID properties
4. The data structure is changing frequently, Hence difficult to use RDBMS
5. you want to scale rapidly and ok to have eventual consistency

And much more difference between SQL and NoSQL mentioned in [this](https://www.guru99.com/sql-vs-nosql.html) blog, but higher-level **above points are critical to determining whether to choose SQL or NoSQL database.**

Elasticsearch in your case is used only for searching and used as secondary storage, hence doesn't add much value to the decision but yeah if you use NoSQL, then how you sync your data can be important factors to provide near real-time search(as NoSQLs are eventual consistent system and might delay the sync operation).